# Writing HTML layout/template within javascript bookmarklet

Tags: javascript, html, template-engine, bookmarklet

I have a bookmarklet which creates a UI for the user to interact with. Currently, I have been using `$('<element>').addClass().css({..});`, but that becomes hard to maintain. Is there a better way to do this?

I have also tried doing something like

```
var html = "<div class='someclass'>";
html += "<more html/>";
html += "</div>"
```

Which is also incredibly hard to maintain. Is there a way I can write html within javascript, or a library like jade that i can use WITHIN a javascript bookmarklet?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, there is a Domain Specific Language implementation in JavaScript to allow you to write more expressive HTML in JavaScript called [Pithy](https://github.com/caolan/pithy).

Please remember that writing large amounts in Pithy is maybe not a good idea and you rather want to use a proper client side templating engine such as [DustJS](http://akdubya.github.io/dustjs/) or [many](http://engineering.linkedin.com/frontend/client-side-templating-throwdown-mustache-handlebars-dustjs-and-more) others.

Comment: templating engines seem to be the opposite of what I want, really. they seem to be var $.template("<h1>%somestuff</h1>", myvar) and %somestuff is replaced with myvar. I just want to write markup.

Comment: What you want is pithy then as I wrote.